# Current Location not showing in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview

I'm trying to show the user's current location in an MKMapView, `mapView`. I ask for permission and I believe all my bases are covered but for some reason the current location does not show up on the map.

Below is the code. Do not mind the segment controls, I just use these to change the map type.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

let annotationId = "annotationID";

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var segControls: UISegmentedControl!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager();
var zoomToUserLocation = false;

// Switch statements for the seg controls.

@IBAction func mapType(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segControls.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    default:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard 
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // We are setting the delegate equal to self here to be able to use the indentifier that deques the annotations.
    locationManager.delegate = self

    // Status of user is variable that speaks directly to (in this case) authorization status
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else if  status != .Denied {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // let annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
}

// If the status changes to authorize when in use or always authorize
// then start updating the location, if not don't do anything.

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

// If the location failed when trying to get users location execute this function
func  locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {

    let coordinate = userLocation.coordinate; // this sets the var coordinates to the location of the user.

    println("User Location = (\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude))");

    if zoomToUserLocation == true {
        let locationOfDevice: CLLocation = userLocation.location // this determines the location of the device using the users location

        let deviceCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationOfDevice.coordinate // determines the coordinates of the device using the location device variabel which has in it the user location.

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1) // this determines the span in which its determined that 1 degree is 69 miles.

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: deviceCoordinate, span: span) // set the center equal to the device coordinates and the span equal to the span variable we have created this will give you the region.

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true);
    } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the MKMapView's `showsUserLocation` property to `true`. It's a boolean property that will display the current location (that pulsing blue dot you refer to - which, can be tinted and is not always blue).

Here's how Apple sums it up in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setShowsUserLocation:)

> This property does not indicate whether the user’s position is actually visible on the map, only whether the map view should try to display it. Setting this property to `true` causes the map view to use the Core Location framework to find the current location and try to display it on the map. As long as this property is `true`, the map view continues to track the user’s location and update it periodically. The default value of this property is `false`.
>
> Showing the user’s location does not guarantee that the location is visible on the map. The user might have scrolled the map to a different point, causing the current location to be offscreen. To determine whether the user’s current location is currently displayed on the map, use the `userLocationVisible` property.

So in your `viewDidLoad` function, you should set this property:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

The `zoomToUserLocation` property does not control the current location dot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to set a custom location first to get the simulator to update and actually set a location (no idea why). What I do is go to `Debug->Location->Apple` just to check that the map location stuff actually works. Then later i set a custom location with coordinates which i find from google maps or similar.

Comment: thanks. I only changed the location to custom after many many failed attempts with the "Apple" location. Still, it doesnt work.

Comment: OK, see @Sam's response, that should do the trick for you then :)